# I need to embed something onto my web page from mixlr.com

Tags: php, html, wordpress, object, embed

I am trying to figure out a way to embed the chat aspect only of our mixlr account onto our home page which http://undergroundhiphopradio.com. I have tried the  method but then again I am not a programmer. Can someone please help us out in figuring out to do this? Thanks! The chat can be viewed on http://mixlr.com/undergroundhiphopradiocom/chat/

Comment: What is that? I basically just want to get that portion of the chat and embed it on my homepage. So http://mixlr.com/undergorundhiphopradiocom/chat/ on my frontpage http://undergroundhiphopradio.com.

Answer (score 0):

These three help pages on Mixlr's website basically sum it up:

- [Embed Mixlr into your website and blog](http://support.mixlr.com/customer/portal/articles/1280419-embed-mixlr-into-your-website-and-blog)
- [Embed Mixlr into your secure SSL (https) page](http://support.mixlr.com/customer/portal/articles/1379353-embed-mixlr-into-your-secure-ssl-https-page)
- [Customize your embeddable player](http://support.mixlr.com/customer/portal/articles/1280440-customise-your-embeddable-player)

Comment: Thanks but yeah I got the player embedded but just want the chat portion.

Comment: If you only want the chat portion, then you'll probably be better off using an `iframe` or loading it from your server, so you can customize exactly what gets viewed. Mixlr (although I'm not that familiar with it) appears to not support only embedding specific portions of the player.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What would be the steps to do so? I was trying to avoid iframes being that it's not HTML5 friendlish..

Comment: I'm not familiar with server-side scripting, but basically you would on your server, (for PHP), you use something called cURL to load get the contents of an external page (e.g. mixlr). Then, you go through that page and find the part of *their* website that you want (e.g. the chat) and send that to *your* website. I wouldn't recommend this if you're not an experienced programmer, because it isn't as simple as other things (e.g. HTML) and it's easy to get wrong and screw things up.

Comment: Hmmm would anyone be able to provide me with a way or procedure of doing this? Thanks

Comment: @user3081398 If you want a developer to create this for you (outside of your company's development team), then perhaps try a freelancing site like [freelancer](freelancer.com) or [topcoder](topcoder.com).